# Equivalent definitions of 1-forms

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, tangent-bundle

Let $M$ be a manifold, then a 1-form $\omega$ is a function that assigns to each point $p \in M$ a linear function or covector. This definition seems natural to me as it exactly captures a 1-form being a section of the cotangent bundle.

On the other hand, we may define the differential of a function $f \in C^\infty(M)$ to be the 1-form:
$$(df)(X) = Xf$$
where $X$ is a vector field.

What is confusing to me is that as the 1-form are now defined over the space of vector fields (or equivalently, the set of all smooth sections of $TM$) and not $M$.

If we specify both a tangent vector and a point then it seems these two definitions are equivalent. The first definition first uses $p \in M$ to define the linear function $\omega_p$, and then evaluates it at some $v \in T_pM$ specified by the vector field $X$. The second definition works the other way around, where $X$ first fixes the tangent vector $v$ and then we evaluate at $p$.

Are these definitions both correct and hence equivalent, or is one an informal way or saying the other?

Comment: read the tensor field characterization lemma in Lee's book. I've also made some remarks about this [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/664740/203278). The key to the equivalence of the definitions is $C^{\infty}(M)$ (multi-)linearity (in more general cases), i.e $(df)(\phi X)=\phi \cdot[(df)(X)]$. The $C^{\infty}(M)$ linearity of the second definition allows you to recover the 'pointwise' definition as sections of the cotangent bundle (using bump functions around each point and a little bit of finessing).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you for your comment. I took at the lemma you mentioned and I am still confused and I don't think I understand differential forms as well as I thought (especially the connection between them acting on $M$ vs a vector field). I did some more reading and it seems the two are equivalent in that in the first definition we have $\omega(p)(v)$ and in the second we have $\omega(v)(p)$, which are obviously the same. Is this correct?

Comment: right, if $\omega$ is a section of the cotangent bundle, and $\Omega$ satisfies the second definition, the relationship is that given a point $p\in M$, a tangent vector $v\in T_pM$ and a vector field $V$such that $V(p)=v$, we have $\omega_p(v)=[\Omega(V)](p)$. But, no these are not "obviously" the same. There is something non-obvious here, and that's the whole point of the lemma (it's 'obvious'/natural to expect that this is the relationship, but proving this is correct is not 'obvious').

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you, maybe obvious was the wrong word to use.